# How to set std::vector as default parameter of template?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I would like to make a template class which has two template arguments. First - **N** is a class of variable default set as `int` and second **container** is a container from `stl` and default is set as `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class N=int, 
      template <class T=N, class Allocator=std::allocator<N>> 
      class container=std::vector>
class foo{
    container<N> cont;
};

int main() 
{
    foo f;
}
```

When I created object `f` of above class without template arguments then the compiler wrote a folowing error:

```
In function 'int main()':
15:9: error: missing template arguments before 'f'
```

I would like `foo` to be equivalent to the `foo<int, std::vector>` declaration.

Where is an issue is my class definition?

Comment: Aside: I would be tempted to write `template <class, class...> class container=std::vector`. You don't need to name (or count!) the parameters of `container`. Notice how you don't mention `T` or `Allocator` after defining them. Otherwise you can't have a `foo<int, std::set>`

Comment: What if the class user wants to use a non-templated container? You are forcing a template to be used. I would  be more inclined to use this instead: `template <class N=int, class container=std::vector<N>> class foo{ container cont; };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++14 or before, you need to write `foo<>` in order to instantiate the template.

From C++17 on, it actually just works as you wrote it because of Class Template Argument Deduction. You might consider updating your C++ language version with `-std=c++17` if your compiler supports it.